# Flutter return parsing dynamic object from service

Tags: flutter, dart

I have created multiple models and using json_serialization

Example Company and Employee and many more.

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'company.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class Company {
  Company({this.id, this.name});

  String id;
  String name;


  factory Company.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$CompanyFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$CompanyToJson(this);
}
```

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'employee.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class Employee {
  Employee({this.id, this.name, this.email, this.phone, this.photo});

  String id;
  String name;
  String email;
  String phone;
  String photo;

  factory Employee.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$EmployeeFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$EmployeeToJson(this);
}
```

Now I want to create a reusable service that can return Stream with type Company, Employee or other types.
I'm using Firebase so the return type is Map.

example service class

```
class BaseService<T> {
  final String collection;
  CollectionReference _collectionRef;

  FirebaseBase({@required this.collection}) {
    _collectionRef = Firestore.instance.collection(collection);
  }

  Stream<List<T>> find() {
    return inColRef.snapshots().map((list) {
      return list.documents.map((doc) {
        final Map<String, dynamic> data = doc.data;
        data['id'] = doc.documentID;
        return data;
      }).toList();
    });
  }
}
```

How do I convert the return data (Map) to a type Company or Employee.

Those class can use the factory of fromJson(data). 
But I can't return a T.fromJson(data).

I would like to get

```
Stream<List<Company>> companies = ServiceBase('companies').find();
Stream<List<Employee>> employees = ServiceBase('employee').find();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you would accomplish the generic assignment using your current code:

```
class BaseService<T> {
  final String collection;
  CollectionReference _collectionRef;

  FirebaseBase({@required this.collection}) {
    _collectionRef = Firestore.instance.collection(collection);
  }

  Stream<List<T>> find() {
    return inColRef.snapshots().map((list) {
      return list.documents.map((doc) {
        final Map<String, dynamic> data = doc.data;
        data['id'] = doc.documentID;
        return _build(data) as T;
      }).toList();
    });
  }

  dynamic _build(final Map<String, dynamic> data) {
      if(collection == 'companies') {
         return Company.fromJson(data);
      } else if(collection == 'employee') {
         return Employee.fromJson(data);
      }
      ... throw if invalid collection passed ? ... 
  }
}
```

This would be called as so:

```
Stream<List<Company>> companies = BaseService<Company>('companies').find();
Stream<List<Employee>> employees = BaseService<Employee>('employee').find();
```

I would recommend that you should a different object structure with the template method pattern such as:

```
class CompanyService extends BaseService<Company> {
      CompanyService() : super('companies');

      Company build(final Map<String, dynamic> data) => Company.fromJson(data);   
}
class EmployeeService extends BaseService<Employee> {
      EmployeeService() : super('employee');

      Employee build(final Map<String, dynamic> data) => Employee.fromJson(data);   
}
abstract class BaseService<T> {
      final String collection;
      CollectionReference _collectionRef;
      BaseService(this.collection) {
         _collectionRef = Firestore.instance.collection(collection);
      }

      T build(final Map<String, dynamic> data);

      Stream<List<T>> find() {
        return inColRef.snapshots().map((list) {
           return list.documents.map((doc) {
           final Map<String, dynamic> data = doc.data;
           data['id'] = doc.documentID;
           return build(data);
        }).toList();
    });
      }
}
```

which would result in the calling code looking something like this:

```
Stream<List<Company>> companies = CompanyService().find();
Stream<List<Employee>> employees = EmployeeService().find();
```

Comment: Thanks Brian. your recommended solution helps. Learned something new.